# Appending a preloaded image to a div

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So,
I did not think that this would that complicated but I cannot figure it out myself.

I preload images in the `<head>` with JS.

```
//PRELOAD THE IMAGES

original = new Image(698, 360);
original.src = "imagenes_png/bosque_mapa.png";

...
```

Then I want to insert the preloaded images ito a `div tag` with the name test, also with JS.

```
//Thats in the head aswell
document.getElementById('test').appendChild(original)
```

That is my `div tag` in the `body`

```
<div id="test"> testext</div>
```

That does not work though. The `div` is still testext

---

For people with the same issue:

Put the

```
document.getElementById('test').appendChild(original)
```

into here

```
$(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ });

$(document).ready(function() {document.getElementById('test').appendChild(original)});
```

Why? Read the comment of David Thomas and follow the posted link!

**Note: That solution requieres jQuery which can be loaded like this:

```
<!-- LINK ZU JQUERY ONLINE-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you're appending, or trying to append, in the `<head>` it's very likely that the elements you're trying to append *to* won't yet exist, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: @DavidThomas ah thanks a lot. I was looking for mistakes in my code or something but that makes sense!

Comment: The easiest way to fix this is to put the script at the end of your `body` element

Comment: @brennan I am working with Joomla so might have to add a little peace of javascript instead of putting the script at the end. But good to know that its not my syntax. I was freaking out why it did not show anything :)